# How to change the default volume level in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building android from source code (AOSP).

How can I change the initial volume level the device will have when it boots up for the first time?

Answer (score 5):

Change the `DEFAULT_STREAM_VOLUME` array (in `frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java`) which contains the default volume for each audio stream type.

Note that the minimum and maximum values of each stream are defined in `MIN_STREAM_VOLUME` and `MAX_STREAM_VOLUME` (in `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/audio/AudioService.java`).

For example, `STREAM_MUSIC` (media volume) is between 0 and 15, and `STREAM_ALARM` and `STREAM_RING` are between 0 and 7.

(I'm using Android 7.1.1)

Comment: can this also be changed on a already runing device? or does it have to be built from scratch? where is the value stored in the system?